# Add an index into mvchtmlstring in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-table, mvchtmlstring

I would like to add an index into mvchtmlstring because I use it in a table. If I need to get the whole list of the data input by user, I need an index so that the system are able to get all the list of data. So this is the example code that I want for:

```
@Html.CommonTextBoxFor(m => m.sample.RefNo, new { @class = "noMarginBottom", Name+="[0]" })
```

The point is I want something like this **Name+="[0]"**

I wish to get back the same name but adding a index after the name. So the name in the html will be like **"name=m.sample.RefNo[0]"**.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're after the [NameFor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.nameextensions.namefor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) helper. You'd use it like so:

```
@Html.CommonTextBoxFor(m => m.sample.RefNo, 
    new { 
        @class = "noMarginBottom", 
        name = Html.NameFor(m => m.sample.RefNo) + "[0]" 
    })
```

Seems like you have a mismatch between your view model and your controller code, though, if you need to do this - if `RefNo` should be indexed, the property should be a collection of some sort, so manually building the name attribute wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will go for a try